http.request body forwarding breaks request
I am writing some sort of proxy and I am trying to forward everything to the "client-server":
const headers = req.headers;
delete headers['content-length'];
const body = '...maybe some content...';

const chunks: any[] = [];

const request = http
    .request(
        url,
        {
            method: req.method,
            headers,
        },
        (msg) => {
            msg.on('data', (data) => chunks.push(data));
        },
    )
    .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
    })
    .on('close', () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'));
    });

request.write(body, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});

request.end();

All in all it is working as I expect it to, but if I send any data (body) in a GET request, then I am getting a Error: socket hang up.
Node's documentation says that most likely the connection closes before the response is received.
The client server accepts a body in a GET and does not refuse the connection or something alike (tested via Postman).
What is happening in Node; Why does the connection close prematurely?

There are no defined semantics for a GET request's body, the client shouldn't be sending one.

If the only data that needs to be sent in the body is indeed a single key/value pair then for a GET request simply include that data on the query string instead.  (And the server would have to look for the data there instead of in the body of course.)

That is not the question ;) the question is, why the connection closes prematurely.

The request Content-Length was causing the premature connection termination.
Node docs state


Sending a 'Content-Length' header will disable the default chunked
encoding.


I was removing the header from the incoming request, for Node to handle it automatically.
Turns out, that Node only computes the content-length in POST/PATCH/PUT requests. In other methods, even by properly using .write() the Content-Length will not be set automatically, causing the premature closure.
To fix this, compute the length of the body on your own and send in in the headers:
const body = '...maybe some content...';

const chunks: any[] = [];

const request = http
    .request(
        url,
        {
            method: req.method,
            headers: {
                ...req.headers,
                'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
            },
        },
        (msg) => {
            msg.on('data', (data) => chunks.push(data));
        },
    )
    .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
    })
    .on('close', () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'));
    });

request.write(body, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});

request.end();

